# Change dynamically Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a problem while changing fragments in my viewpager. In specific, my fragment is replaced with an empty one.

Here's some code:

```
 public void replaceFragment() {
        supportManager.getFragments().set(1,getNewFragment()));
        pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        menuControl.setView(1);//this  just changes the fragment to be shown
    }//here is where i change the fragment

    //and here is the adapter
    public class SimplePageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    final List<Fragment> fragment;
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public SimplePageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragment) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentManager = fm;
        this.fragment=fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        return fragment.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragment.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object o) {
        return POSITION_NONE;//I read that this is for making notifyDataSet work
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem?  An error?  Show your logcat, the error....something

Comment: No errors, the problem is that the old fragment is replaced with an empty one.

Comment: show your fragments?